# Define range of digit for an already defined pattern in regex

Tags: java, regex

As wierd i'm missing something i can't find in SO answers already given

I created a regex to match these requirements :

- A string that match any number or these alphanumeric (_,-,whitespace)
- this string must be in range of 3 to 23 chars length.

I made up the regex for match as a start `^[a-zA-Z0-9_ -]*$` which normally match the first requirement

Now i change the * quantifier match to give a range of digit such as d{3,23} such as the regex would look like

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_ -]\d{3,23}$
```

Well, it doesn't matches. Some help would be nice also with some explaination please.

Comment: Maybe `^(?=(?:\D*\d){3,23}\D*$)[\w\s-]*$`? See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/nzG4HH/1)

Comment: Please revise the title: I think you asked for something different than *define range of **digit***

Comment: What you suggest then?

Comment: If you do not want to specify an allowed range for digits only, why mention them in the title? And then `to give a range of digit` in the question. If you want to set a char limit on the whole regex, just state that.

Comment: I think the content of the question is crystal clear with what requirements needed to be met. Also i added my thinking process to it. I see what is ambigous or false in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you might have an extra `\d` in the expression, and maybe this would work:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_ -]{3,23}$
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to only match the string meeting the first requirement when there are 3 to 24 digits in it you need a `(?=(?:\D*\d){3,23}\D*$)` lookahead at the start:

```
^(?=(?:\D*\d){3,23}\D*$)[a-zA-Z0-9_ -]*$
```

Since in Java `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` can be written as `\w` safely use

```
^(?=(?:\D*\d){3,23}\D*$)[\w -]*$
```

And to match whitespace, you may use `\s` instead of a regular space:

```
^(?=(?:\D*\d){3,23}\D*$)[\w\s-]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nzG4HH/1) (modified since the pattern is tested against a single multiline string).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=(?:\D*\d){3,23}\D*$)` - there must be 3 to 23 sequences of 0+ non-digit chars followed with a digit, and then any 0+ non-digit chars to the end of the string
- `[\w\s-]*` - 0+ letters,  digits, `_`, whitespace and `-` chars
- `$` - to the end of the string.

Java usage example:

```
boolean valid  = s.matches("(?=(?:\\D*\\d){3,23}\\D*$)[\\w\\s-]*");
```

Note that `String#matches` requires a full string match, thus the anchors are redundant.